# How do I know if my huffman tree is correct?

Tags: encoding, compression, huffman-code

The question asked to:

> Create a Huffman tree and codes for the following numbers: 24, 55, 13,
> 67, 88, 36, 17, 61, 24, 76

So I created this tree:

[image: depth 5 tree]

But since there are multiple trees possible, how will I know whether my tree is right or not as there are multiple elements with same frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreting the "numbers" as symbols as opposed to frequencies, we then have the set of frequencies {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}. Due to having more than one choice at some of the steps in the Huffman algorithm, there is more than one possible resulting topology. Here are the three topologically distinct trees you can get, depending on the choices you make:

[image: three trees]

For each of those, you can arbitrarily choose which of your symbols to put at each length. For the first two trees, the 2 has to be symbol 24, but the remaining eight symbols can be split however you like among each group of four. For each of those two trees, that is 70 possible unique length assignments. For the third tree, again the 2 has to be symbol 24, but the remaining symbols can be split as you like into the groups of two and six, for 28 possible choices.

Having made those choices, you now can assign codes to each leaf, where at each branch you can independently and arbitrarily assign 0 to the left branch and 1 to the right branch, *or* 1 to the left branch, and 0 to the right branch. For each tree and symbol lengths assignment, that gives 256 possible code assignments.

All told, there are 43,008 possible codes that can result from the Huffman algorithm. *All of these choices are correct.* They all result in the same optimal number of bits in the message (32).

Here is [another example of multiple Huffman tree topologies for a single set of frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792900/1180620).

Comment: well i think i misunderstood the questions. "the shortest path has one of the lowest frequencies, 24. The leaf with frequency 88 should have the shortest path to the root" well 24 is the only number that's repeated twice in the given set so it should have the highest frequency, 2. 88, on the other hand, is not repeated, therefore it's frequency is 1 as all other elements. Am i somehow misinterpreting the question here?

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted. I read the numbers as _frequencies_ of the symbols, not as the symbols themselves. Are you saying you could replace the numbers with a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, and i?